# Behavior of the ScalingFunctions option

Tags: plotting

The documentation of [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) has been improved in V10.4. Its use in making list plots is now documented. However, after reading the new `ListPlot` documentation, I don't quite understand this feature:

[image]

An example given in the documentation for `ListPlot` is

```
ListPlot[{1, 5, 10, 35, 60, 75, 140}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, {-Log[#] &, Exp[-#] &}}]
```

[image]

Can someone explain it?

BTW, the above figure is not well reproduced on my machine if I do an in-place rerun (a buy-one-get-one-free feature?):

[image]

The y ticks are obviously messed up somehow.

Comment: So you plotted `ListPlot[-Log[{1, 5, 10, 35, 60, 75, 140}]]`, only with nicer ticks on the $y$-axis. The inverse of the scaling function might be needed for internal calculations, so it's nice to supply it.

Comment: Have you [searched on this site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ScalingFunctions)?  Many answers explain its use in various situations.

Comment: @J.M. No, I didn't plot another one. I just reran the identical code as shown in the post and got very different plot from the one in the documentation. I suspect the ticks are not properly handled by the v10.4 release.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I did search its use. But my question is different from those posts. I'm just curious about the double-function syntax, which is not discussed before.

Comment: I was explaining what happened. Except for the ticks, the snippet I gave yields the same points as in the one with the `ScalingFunctions` setting. And I already said the inverse of the scaling function might be needed in some internal calculations, so you supply it along with the function itself.

Comment: `ScalingFunctions` is not a v10.4 addition, nor has it been previously undocumented. It first appeared in V8. AFAIK, the only change in V10.4 is very welcome improved documentation.

Comment: @J.M., Thanks. Now I get it. But the exposure of an inverse function looks not so stylish.

Comment: As I'm sure you're aware, most functions are not so readily invertible. This design seems like the most expedient choice, since it allows the user to supply a (hopefully well-tuned) routine for numerically inverting his hard-to-invert scaling function.

Comment: In my docs the example is `ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", {weibull, InverseFunction[weibull]}, None}`. I only looked at this for 5 sec after reading this question but was not clear about the syntax

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch the example shown in the post is from the options section of `ListPlot`. As @J.M. clarified, this syntax is kind of an auxillary use to ensure the scaling can be correctly done, which is not so stylish though.